# Automatic Deletion of Moved Message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, when I move a message from Unread Mail to a folder, it appears in both places.  I want it to disappear from Unread Mail automatically once it has moved.  How do I accomplish this?  Thanks, Perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

Unread Mail is a default search folder which cannot be customised.
The intent is to display all Unread Mail in your Mailbox.

Can you not just use your inbox? You are able to favourite your inbox and other folders at the top of outlook where your Unread Mail search folder is.

You can also change the view settings to filter out mail that has been read.

If you want to imitate the functionality of the Unread mail search folder, you might be able to include the specific folders you wish to search by creating a new custom search folder.

1. List item
2. Right Click Search Folders -> New Search Folder
3. Scroll to the bottom, "create a custom search folder", then click "Choose"
4. Give it a name
5. Click Criteria
6. On the "More choices" tab choose "Only items that are unread".
7. On the Advanced tab, add the "In Folder" field from the "All Mail Items" category
8. Choose "contains" from the condition, and type the folder name in the Value.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying here.
The problem is, outlook does not mark a message as read until you scroll away from that message.
So, select the desired message, select some other message(which will mark it as read) and then move it.

FYI, like Trissy said, "Unread mail" is a search folder. To compare, it similar to windows search results. The files(emails) are not physically in that folder..they are just links pointing to those emails.